# Is it possible to execute a function in shell by calling it with parenthesis

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I execute a function in shell by calling it with parenthesis i.e.:

```
my_func()
{
    echo $0
    echo $1
} 

my_func("aa","bb")
```

and not like that

```
my_func "aa" "bb"
```

Comment: You can't.  Why do you want to apply some other language's syntax to the shell?

Comment: @MarkReed: post that as the answer. It's an odd question, but one with a simple answer.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If the problem is "I don't like the shell's function call syntax", it's not much of a problem -- and if it is, the solution is to use another language, or to write your own shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, in most shells, bash included, `(` and `)` are, with the exception of the empty `()` form a reserved control operator.  You could escape or quote, but that's hardly useful.

You can slightly abuse `{` `}`  *brace expansion*:

```
my_func {1,2,3}
```

since `{1,2,3}` expands to "1 2 3", though it has other features too. You must ensure there are no (unquoted) spaces within, `{1, 2, 3}` is treated exactly as-is. Literal commas must be quoted or `\` escaped. You need a space after the function name, or it will do something rather different.

Or, if you really want to play games, the `[` `]` can be misused too, not entirely unlike the way `[` (aka `test`) works, at the expense of non-trivial parsing. This is a passable though imperfect example which shows why:

```
function my_func () 
{
   local IFS=" ,"
   set -- $*; 

   for ((ff=1; ff<=$#; ff++)); do
         printf "\$%i=<%s>  " $ff "${!ff}"
    done
    printf "\n"
}

my_func [ "a",b,c ]
my_func [ 1, 2 ,3 ]
```

`bash` is not `tcl`...  In case you're trying to write a program which is valid as two or more different languages, you should search instead for [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29) programs.

I'm still working on a way to [replace `{` and `}` with `BEGIN` and `END`](http://c-faq.com/cpp/slm.html).

Comment: This only works for unquoted arguments: try `my_func [ "a b", c, d ]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Why do you want to apply some other language's syntax to the shell?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I execute a function in shell by calling it with parenthesis?

Try this:

```
my_func "(" ")"
```

Comment: Of course that passes the strings `(` and `)` as arguments to the function. I'm certain you know that, but the OP may not.

Comment: @KeithThompson Of course, and I upvoted the other answer, he deserves some rep :)